# Cannot add empty folder

Tags: git

I added an empty folder named "test" in master folder and I want to update my github.

I typed

```
git add .
git commit -m "all file"
```

and it show

```
#On Branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Why?

Comment: Did you add/change any files into/in the repo?

Comment: you might be modifying files of type specified in .gitignore

Comment: If you've added files and merged, then there are no changes, so your status should be showing as clean. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Now, I want push them to git hub, but I couldn't.

Comment: use `git push origin master`

Comment: Git does not track empty folders. you said you created a folder -- but didnt mention any files in it. if there are none, git will ignore the folder

Comment: @NevikRehnel,Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git does not track directories. It tracks files. Directly from [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) (emphasis added)

> ### Can I add empty directories?
>
> Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) **only permits files to be listed**, and nobody competent enough to make the change to allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to remedy it.
> Directories are added automatically when adding files inside them. That is, directories never have to be added to the repository, and are not tracked on their own.
> You can say "git add " and it will add the files in there.
> **If you really need a directory to exist in checkouts you should create a file in it**. .gitignore works well for this purpose (there is also a tool MarkEmptyDirs using the .NET framework which allows you to automate this task); you can leave it empty or fill in the names of files you do not expect to show up in the directory.

So as the FAQ suggests, if you really need to add an empty directory to your repo you can create any file in it. I usually put an empty `.gitkeep` file inside the empty folder I want to track and that allows me to add it to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

did you change anything in the folder. `git status` is used to show the changes you have made in repo since last commit.

or may be the files you changed are included in the `.gitignore` file in the repo folder

#### update1:

if you want to know the changes either use `git diff` mybranch..master to know the differrence betwween two branches or you can also use graphical difference tool such as gitk, gitg. you can install these by command apt-get install gitk

### graphical differenc tools:

```
$ gitk
$ gitg
```

Comment: I create a branch and add some file and then merge to master branch.that is all I did.

Comment: @LateBloomer if you commited the changes and merged then nothing will shows in status. if you want to know the changes either use `git diff mybranch..master` to know the differrence betwween two branches or you can also use graphical difference tool such as `gitk`, `gitg`. you can install these by command `apt-get install gitk`

Answer (score 0):

first use

```
git add [files]
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

then

```
git commit -m "your comment"
```

GIT has excellent documentation
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: If there are files that need to be added, they would have shown up in the result of `git status`. This isn't really an answer the the problem. Actually, we don't even know what the problem is.